# RTL Charts in React native

Tags: react-native, graph, charts

After spending many hours for looking Graphs in RTL for react native,I found nothing with respect to RTL. Is there any charts or Graphs available in RTL for react native?

Comment: I have looked on the internet and I couldn't find out what RTL is. Real time something? Ready to learn? I assume its *right to left* according to the answer you accepted, but this **does not** seem to be a widely used acronym or set of words.

Comment: After reading this [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/In-right-to-left-languages-are-chart-axes-drawn-differently?share=1), I can only assume you have an Arabic context

Comment: yes this is used for Arabic and Hebrew content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it's pretty simple.
You can pick any chart library, for instance this one (used for the examples below)
https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts

In RTL all you need to do is to reverse order of the array you pass to your chart:
For instance if you have:

```
const data = [50, 10, 30, 20, -10, -20, 0, 25, -5, 10]
```

Then in RTL you want to pass this data to your chart:

```
const dataRTL = [...data].reverse() 
/** [10, -5, 25, 0, -20, -10, 20, 30, 10, 50]  **/
```

If you have an X axis you also need to reverse the data of this axis
If you want to put Y axis on the right side, you can switch order of your component (see example below)

**Example without RTL**

[image: Chart without RTL]

```js
 render() {
    const data = [50, 10, 30, 20, -10, -20, 0, 25, -5, 10]
    const xLabel = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

    return (
      <View>
        <View style={{ height: 300, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <YAxis
            data={data}
            contentInset={{ top: 20, bottom: 20 }}
            svg={{ fill: 'black', fontSize: 12 }}
            numberOfTicks={8}
            formatLabel={(value) => `${value}ºC`}
          />
          <LineChart
            style={{ flex: 1, marginRight: 10 }}
            data={data}
            svg={{ stroke: 'rgb(134, 65, 244)' }}
            contentInset={{ top: 20, bottom: 20 }}
          >
            <Grid />
          </LineChart>

        </View>
        <View>
          <XAxis
            style={{ marginHorizontal: 10 }}
            data={data}
            formatLabel={(value, index) => xLabel[index]}
            contentInset={{ left: 22, right: 0 }}
            svg={{ fontSize: 12, fill: 'black' }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
```

**Example with RTL**

[image: Chart with RTL]

```js
  render() {
    const data = [50, 10, 30, 20, -10, -20, 0, 25, -5, 10]
    const dataRTL = [...data].reverse()
    const xLabel = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
    const xLabelRTL = [...xLabel].reverse()

    return (
      <View>
        <View style={{ height: 300, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <LineChart
            style={{ flex: 1, marginLeft: 10 }}
            data={dataRTL}
            svg={{ stroke: 'rgb(134, 65, 244)' }}
            contentInset={{ top: 20, bottom: 20 }}
          >
            <Grid />
          </LineChart>
          <YAxis
            data={dataRTL}
            contentInset={{ top: 20, bottom: 20 }}
            svg={{ fill: 'black', fontSize: 12 }}
            numberOfTicks={8}
            formatLabel={(value) => `${value}ºC`}
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <XAxis
            style={{ marginHorizontal: 10 }}
            data={dataRTL}
            formatLabel={(value, index) => xLabelRTL[index]}
            contentInset={{ left: 0, right: 22 }}
            svg={{ fontSize: 12, fill: 'black' }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
```

( Note that I also put the YAxis below the LineChart component in order to put the Y axis on the right side )